# Shortcut to filter 'Find All References' for only guaranteed Assignments?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

## Overview

When working in a C# project, Visual Studio 15 has a shortcut to `Find All References`, which will display all references of the variable being used throughout the Solution in the `'...' references` panel.

Is it possible to view just a subset of the result of `Find All References` where the variable is being assigned to?

## Example

Given this contrived `Foo.cs`:

```cs
public class Bar
{
    private int val;
    public Bar(int val) { this.val = val; }
    public SetValue(int val) { this.val = val; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Bar bar = new Bar(111);

    public Foo()
    {
        bar = new Bar(222);
        bar.SetValue(333);
        Modify(ref bar, 444);
        Set(out bar, 555);
    }

    public void Modify(ref Bar toModify, int val)
    {
        toModify.SetValue(val);
    }

    public void Set(out Bar toSet, int val)
    {
        toSet = new Bar(val);
    }
}
```

If I place my cursor on the declaration of `Foo.bar` and hit `Shift+F12` for `Find All References` (or right click and select the same option) I get the following 4 lines:

[image]

I would like a convenient way just get the subset of references that specifically consist of guaranteed assignments to `bar`.

Ideally I would like to have a shortcut similar to `Shift+F12` that performs such an action, for example `Ctrl+Shift+F12`.

Specifically when performed, I would like the `Find All References` results window to:

- **Include** assignments such as `bar = new Bar(222)` (ignoring the initial definition)
- **Include** passing it as an `out` parameter which is guaranteed to assign a value to it.
- **Ignore** passing by `ref`, since that is not guaranteed to perform an assignment. For the sake of this question I'm *only* interested in assignments that are *guaranteed*.
- **Ignore** any other references to `bar`.

In the case of this example, I want to only see the lines with values `222` and `555` since those are the only **guaranteed** assignments:

[image]

## The search bar

I am aware that there is a search bar to the top-right of `Find All References` results window and that I can use this to filter the existing set of references returned by `Shift+F12`, and so can filter for `=` (which must be escaped with `\`) and `out`:

[image]
[image]

However this is not ideal

- It does not appear to support regex and so searching for `=` and `out` have to be performed separately.
- More importantly it is not syntax-aware. It just string matches which can easily result in false positives and false negatives:

```cs
    // False positive, 'bar' not assigned but line contains '='
    var derp = bar.GetValue();
    if(bar == null) {...}
    bar.SetString("===");

    // False negative,'bar' assigned but line does not contain '='
    Bar
        = new Bar(666);
```

## Desired Solution

To re-iterate: Is it possible to perform basic syntax analysis in a manner similar to `Find All References`, but only return references where a guaranteed assignment is performed on the variable in question?

The goal is to use this in large projects where there are thousands of references to a given variable, but only a handful of assignments, and to be able to have some mechanism for quickly seeing those specific lines of code at a glance.

If there is a way to add a keyboard shortcut to just perform `Find All References` and auto-fill `\=` in the search bar that would be *acceptable*, but not ideal due to false positives/negatives as mentioned above. Since the false negative is so unlikely, at least it would make narrowing the references down to a smaller subset.

An ideal solution would leverage Visual Studio's knowledge of the code to locate all instances where the given variable is being assigned syntactically.

Comment: ReSharper has this but it slows down VS responsiveness. Anyway it's a huge timeserver on other fronts so I suggest you try it out if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a requested feature on [VisualStudio's UserVoice page](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/6210373-find-all-assignments)

When digging in the [DotNet/Roslyn Github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/), there is an issue that discusses the exact feature I am looking for: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/22545

Specifically the ability to filter the `Find All References` results by what kind of reference, including 'Write' which is what I was looking for:
[image]

As of this post, it is marked as being included in the still unreleased [16.0.P2 release milestone](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/milestone/36).